# AngularJS handling missing properties in model

Tags: angularjs

Suppose my model has some `info` field and this info could have a "prop" property.

I am rendering a div and would like it to have an attribute with the value of that property.

This is simple enough using `<div attr="{{info.prop}}"></div>`.

But if `info` does not have the `prop` or has it with a null value it renders 
`<div attr></div>`

How can I prevent `attr` from being added to the div?

And in a more general way how can I examine the model and add the attribute only if some conditions apply?

I suppose I could have the model include a special function in the scope and use  `<div {{attrGetter()}}"></div>` or `<div {{attrGetter(info.prop)}}"></div>` and have this logic in the controller. 
But I wanted to know if there are better/other ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where I would use a directive, where-in the `link` function you have access to the elements attributes:

```
.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            if (scope.info.hasOwnProperty("prop"))
                attrs["attr"] = scope.info.prop
        }
    }
});
```

And throw this directive onto your target element:

```
<div my-directive></div>
```

Comment: directive would be the best way to do it if you are really trying to avoid rendering the extra markup

Comment: Thanks,
what if I have `prop1` and `prop2` ?
would you add another if to the same directive? or is there a more general way to do this?
maybe an element directive `"<add-attr if="info.hasOwnProperty('prop')" attr="myAttr" value="info.prop">` and have it modify the parent element... maybe I will go that way...